# ¿Cómo especificar la ruta para importar un archivo específico?

Tags: python, librería

Intento importar un archivo Python en un notebook jupyter de Anaconda pero mientras que funcione bien hasta una hora pero hoy me dice que hay un `NameError`.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-28aefea88e42> in <module>
      1 import imp
      2 from stocker import Stocker
----> 3 imp.reload(stocker)

NameError: name 'stocker' is not defined
```

También intenté :

```
import importlib
from stocker import Stocker
importlib.reload(stocker)
```

Pero no funciona tampoco.

Por seguro tengo sun archivo stocker.py que llamo desde el notebook

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por consiguiente pienso que esta un error de ruta pero aunque importa la ruta del carpeta en el path con `sys.path.append(r'C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Luxurynsight\Finance')` no funciona. Incluso lo agrega cada vez.

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python36.zip
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\DLLs
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\extensions
C:\Users\antoi\.ipython
C:\Users\antoi\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpxi5uysfy
C:\Users\antoi\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpvwwnclc1
C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Luxurynsight\Finance
C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Luxurynsight\Finance
C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Luxurynsight\Finance
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-0bf8ff56cd18> in <module>
      6 import importlib
      7 from stocker import Stocker
----> 8 importlib.reload(stocker)
      9 
     10 import imp

NameError: name 'stocker' is not defined
```

Comment: fíjate que en Meta decidimos etiquetar con [tag:python] todo lo que tiene que ver con este lenguaje. Si además la versión es relevante, etiquetamos con la correspondiente.

Answer (score 2):

Para que `importlib.reload()` te pueda recargar un módulo, es necesario que el símbolo que representa a ese módulo esté definido.

En tu caso haces `importlib.reload(stocker)` y por lo que se ve el símbolo `stocker` no es conocido, razón por la cual te sale el error `name 'stocker' is not defined`.

La razón es que, aunque el módulo lo cargaste como parte de la instrucción `from stocker import Stocker`, esa forma de importar sólo te define el símbolo `Stocker` (que seguramente es una clase), y no el símbolo `stocker` (que debería ser un módulo). Necesitas añadir también:

```
import stocker
```

Por otro lado, para que este `import` funcione, el archivo `stocker.py` debe estar en la ruta buscada por python (que puedes consultar en `sys.path`, variable que es una lista a la que puedes añadir más elementos si fuera necesario). En todo caso, entiendo que el módulo sí se halla en un lugar que python pueda encontrar, pues de no ser así ya te habría saltado un error en el `from stocker import Stocker`.